# Bluetooth PAN connection between several Windows machines

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, pan

I am looking for a way to connect several Windows 7 machines via Bluetooth PAN.

It is easy to create PAN connection between two PCs playing PANU role (make one discoverable and connect to it via another).

Is it possible to have one machine to play GN role so that others can connect to it?
If it is not possible with Microsoft stack, are there any other stacks that allow this?